# How do I transfer funds from an exchange to a wallet I control?

Tags: wallets, exchanges

This Q&A was spawned by the fact there's no one good place with this information. All answers will be wikis. A few of us are going to be collaborating on this effort. Please keep one answer per exchange. Feel free to add whatever you can.

The answers are solely going to cover transferring from an exchange to a wallet you already have. If you need help generating a wallet, see (todo: insert links here).

Thank you.

1. Poloniex
2. Kraken
3. Gatecoin
4. ???

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm new to this and my question might look silly but could you explain where I can find "the address" to tap it into the wallet?
I understood the first one but isn't an address that can be used for any wallet, like it was generated by the broker and sent to your email address so I can use it whenever I want to withdraw some ETH?
Thanks,
J

Answer (score 6):

## Kraken

1. Log in to your Kraken account.
2. Click on the "Funding Tab" and then "Withdraw" and then at the bottom, "Ether (ETH)"

[image: 2]

3. Click the "+ Add address" button.
4. Add a description and your ether address. No need to fill in the data field.
5. Save the address.
6. Click the back button.
7. Select the adddress you just created from the dropdown.
8. Enter the amount.
9. Click the green "Review Withdrawal" Button.
10. Check it over one last time and click "Confirm Withdrawal".
11. You can now view the withdrawal to see the status. Usually this is pretty quick. Once the "Initiated" status changes to "Success" you can access your Ether wallet on an blockchain explorer or in your wallet client and see the balance.

That's it!

---

A user on reddit recently made a video specifically for Kraken -> Ethereum Wallet. [If you prefer videos, check it out.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/4nf6wi/how_to_withdraw_eth_from_kraken_to_your_mist/)

Answer (score 4):

## Poloniex

1. Login to your Poloniex account
2. In the upper right, look for the “Balances” drop down:

[image: Balances]

3. Click Deposits and Withdrawals
4. Scroll down until you see ETH and click "Withdraw" over on the right hand side.
5. This will pop down a menu-thingy.

[image: Withdraw]

6. Enter your address and the amount you would like to withdraw. Then click the WITHDRAW button.
7. Poloniex will now send you an email. Open you email and click the link they provided.
8. You will taken to a "WITHDRAWAL CONFIRMED" page.
9. Type your address into Etherchain or Etherscan to see if the transaction made it. For some reason, it sometimes takes a couple more minutes than usual on Poloniex. You can check the status on the [deposit/withdrawal history](https://www.poloniex.com/depositHistory) page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like MyEtherWallet that allows you to download your own key, just copy it over to your Parity keys folder.  Done.

Answer (score -1):

ad. Poloniex, generally the procedure is OK, however, usually after withdrawal there is a small rest, to say ETH 0.0000023, so what to do to clear my account to the scratch

Comment: Please ask this in another question. Best would be to ask on Poloniex support or reddit as this is clearly out of Ethereum stackexchange scope, so you would be flagged as off topic.